# programmatically deleted cached persistant Playready License

Tags: c#, silverlight, drm, playready

I am currently working on a system where there is a clear use case to over write the current Playready DRM licence that the player is currently using to decrypt a live stream. (using Silverlight and SMFPlayer) - this is to clear the current licence to force a request for a new one for the same content.

We could achieve this by destroying the player element and and reloading in the same stream url. using non persistant licences.

however we would like not to have to refresh the player object.

Is there a way to programmatically clear the cached Playready licence?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to programmatically achieve this. The only Silverlight methods available to access the license store are on the [LicenseManagement class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.licensemanagement(v=vs.95).aspx) which simply allows you to check whether licenses are stored for a given key ID.

The fact that you need to do this at all tells me that something is not as it should be in your licensing workflow - if you can expand on what your actual goals are (either by editing this question or by posting a new one), I might be able to propose a better solution.

Comment: You are correct this is not the correct way that the workflow should work, it was to try and meet a strange requirement for a client. I have a work around in place, where by I am creating short lived licenses, As the it is streaming a live stream and not Vod content, the player will not "stop" once the licence expires, but it does allow me to force the player to request a new licence by refreshing the playlist. It is a temp solution while awaiting Key rotation

Comment: I see. Will the final solution involve PlayReady Scalable Key Rotation? I would be interested to learn more about your experiences with Scalable Key Rotation if you are willing to share, as we are also working with that technology for a few upcoming projects. You can contact me via saares@axinom.com if you are interested in exchanging thoughts on the matter.